# Нужен ли bonjour для windows 10 1703 для работы с avahi?

Tags: windows-10

Как я понял с 1703 windows 10 перестал поддерживать NetBIOS, посему компы с samba в сетевом окружении не видны, а те что видны (windows машины) используют WSD обнаружение. Далее как я понял надо поднять avahi там же где samba. Но вот вопрос, Умеет ли windows 10 1703 mDNS? Или нужно ставить bonjour для работы с avahi ?